# How to send the total amount to be paid to paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to send the total amount to be paid by the customer with `<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{$total}">` where `{$total}` holds the total amount(smarty) but when I click buy now button of paypal,it shows amount to be paid as 0.00 . Whats wrong ?My code is :

```
Total :
{$total}

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="SVXVEBF9CH4YU">

<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{$total}">

<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I am testing it in `localhost`,is this creating that problem ?

Comment: Look at your generated HTML. The Smarty/PHP code is not relevant. This will also help you to narrow down the problem.

Comment: whats wrong with my smarty code ?

Comment: Try giving a numerical value.What happens ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can't override the amount dynamically, is because you have a so-called 'PayPal hosted button'.
With a hosted button, the amount is stored on PayPal's side and can't be overwritten with the 'amount' variable.
You'll either want to use a non-hosted button (as Peter Szymkowski is using in his answer), or use the [BMUpdateButton](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_BMUpdateButton) API call to dynamically update the button's amount.

An example request for BMUpdateButton would look as follows:

```
USER=Your API username
PWD=Your API password
SIGNATURE=Your API signature
VERSION=82.0
HOSTEDUBTTONID=The value of <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="">
BUTTONTYPE=The type of button. E.g. BUYNOW
BUTTONCODE=The type of code you want to get back. E.g. HOSTED
L_BUTTONVAR0=amount=The new amount with a period as separator
L_BUTTONVAR1=item_name=Optional: a new item name if you wish
```

Similary, you could also use the [BMCreateButton](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_BMCreateButton) API to create a new button, or use the [BMButtonSearch](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_BMButtonSearch) API to search through a list of all your stored hosted buttons (to find the hosted_button_id of your button automatically, for example)

The reason to use a hosted button is because it's more secure. A non-hosted, unencrypted button would basically leave the amounts open to manipulation. Fraudulent transactions waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

paypal amount key is `amount_1`, not `amount` so...

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="{$total}">
```

Edit:

**This works perfect for me.**

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="platnosci">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="arest@arest.pl">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.google.pl/paypal.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item description">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="34.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="PLN">
    <input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://www.arest.pl">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="tester">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Make sure your {$total} is not blank

Comment: @Nitish check my new answer please

Comment: That's not correct. It's `amount_1` (and `amount_n` for any subsequent items), but that only applies when 'cmd' is _cart.

Answer (score -1):

Just try this code

```
<input name=AMT value="{$total}">
```

Corrected,

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value={$total}>
```

Comment: Sorry, this code is used in PayPal sandbox NVP **SetExpressCheckout**