# paypal html form not working

Tags: html, forms, paypal

I try to create an auto filled paypal form for a webshop:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" class="input-form" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" value="utf-8" name="charset">
    <input type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" name="cmd">
    <input type="hidden" value="{somehash}" name="hosted_button_id">
    <input type="hidden" value="17" name="item_number">
    <input type="hidden" value="kosár és szállítás" name="item_name">
    <input type="hidden" value="9990" name="amount">
    <input type="hidden" value="HUF" name="currency_code">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="upload">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="no_shipping">
    <input type="hidden" value="http://www.mydomain.loc/" name="return">
    <input type="image" border="0" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" class="button submit-button image-button">
    <img width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
</form>
```

The {somehash} gave me the paypal account owner (I never had an account). My problem, that I get something like this after submit:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlVbx.jpg)
It contains nothing but the item name...

```
<div id="miniCartContent" class="body clearfix" style="height: 1083px;">
    <div class="" id="miniCart">
    <h3>Your order summary</h3>
    <div class="small head wrap">
        Descriptions
        <span class="amount">Amount</span>
    </div>
    <ol class="small wrap items ">
        <li class="seller1">
            <ul>
            <li class="itmdet" id="multiitem1">
                <ul class="item1">
                    <li class="dark">
                        <span class="name">
                            <a id="showname0" title="" href="#name0" class="autoTooltip">
                                kosár és szállítás
                                <span class="accessAid">kosár és szállítás</span>
                            </a>
                        </span>
                        <span class="secondary noamt amount">0</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="secondary qty">
                        <p class="group">
                            <label for="item_price"><span class="labelText">Item price: </span></label>
                            <span class="field">
                                <input type="text" value="" name="amount" id="item_price" size="6" maxlength="15">
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="secondary">
                        Quantity: 1
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="action">
                            <span class="buttonAsLink">
                                <input type="submit" onclick="PAYPAL.Checkout.Slider.showPanelMsg('cartMsg')" class="action updateSubmit" name="update.x" id="updateTotals0" value="Update">
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul></ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
<div class="wrap items totals item1">
    <ul>
        <li class="small heavy">
            Item total <span class="amount">0</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I don't know what to do, I read a dozen tutorial, but had no succes :S
Any idea?

**edit:**

Testing from dev server, localhost (but I don't think it counts)...

Comment: The official paypal site has a wizard that creates HTML form code: https://www.paypal.com/pdn-item

Comment: I don't have paypal account...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<input type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" name="cmd">` to `<input type="hidden" value="_xclick" name="cmd">`
And instead of `<input type="hidden" value="{somehash}" name="hosted_button_id">`, use `<input type="hidden" value="{somehash}" name="business">`

`_s-xclick` is meant for secured and/or so called 'hosted' buttons, where the details of the buttton are stored on someone's PayPal acccount.
To specify the recipient of funds with PayPal Website Payments Standard (the product you're using), you need to use the `business` parameter.

Comment: Ok I'll try it. I think the stored button is for constant amounts, and a webshop operates with altering amounts and quantities, so the cmd type is really wrong...

Comment: I'm 95% sure, that it's not possible with a stored button id I referred as "{somehash}". Is there a way not to give the email address? (just customer id, or something like that???)

Comment: You will need to specify a receiver; be it an email address, or a 'secure PayPal account ID'. Alternatively you can use the BMCreateButton API to create a hosted button automatically via an API call: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825694/how-to-send-the-total-amount-to-be-paid-to-paypal/7841854#7841854